# Display selected value in spinner first

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner

How can display the selected item first in `spinner` list?
Assume `Rainy` was retrieved from `MySQL` and now it should display the `Rainy item` first. How do I achieve this ?

```
  Spinner Weather;

   private void showEmployee(String json){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            String weather = c.getString(Config.TAG_WEATHER);
            RetrieveWeather(weather);
            // what should add here

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

     public void RetrieveWeather(String a)
        {
            String[] arr = new String[]{"Sunny","Cloudy","Rainy","Thunderstorm"};
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            String weather = a;
            list.add(weather);
            for(String s:arr){
                if(!list.contains(s)){
                    list.add(s);
                }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Weather.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Spinner Weather;
String weather;
int pos = 0;
String[] arr = new String[]{"Sunny","Cloudy","Rainy","Thunderstorm"};

   private void showEmployee(String json){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            weather = c.getString(Config.TAG_WEATHER);
            RetrieveWeather(weather);
            // what should add here

            Weather.setSelection(pos);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

     public void RetrieveWeather(String a)
        {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            String weather = a;
            list.add(weather);
            for(String s:arr){
                if(!list.contains(s)){
                    list.add(s);
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
               if(weather.equals(list.get(i)))
               {
                  pos = i;
               }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            Weather.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: if I have 10 item, I need to write until 10 ?

Comment: No.You can just put it in a loop to do that. Did it work for you in the present state?

Comment: It actually depends on the sequence of strings in your `list` and not on the sequence in your `arr`. I just gave an example to give you a rough idea. Look at the order of strings in your `list`.

Comment: How to let it display thunderstorm ? I have no idea

Comment: What happens when you select Sunny? Does it crash?

Comment: `pos` is assigned but never used..should I add it as global?

Comment: Oh yes it should be global.

Comment: Thanks, work like charm :D and you have put them in loop

Comment: Cheers...Happy coding :)